# How to Find 4th Degree Complex Roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am familiar with using synthetic division to factor out any real roots, break the problem down to a quadratic equation, and use the quadratic formula to find any complex roots. However, in the case of no real roots how do we go about finding the complex roots. I have done a lot of looking around and have not found specific help.

Example Characteristic equation: 
$$
r^4 + 8r +16 = 0
$$
Answer is given as:
$$
2i, -2i 
$$
Edit: middle term is squared
$$
r^4 + 8r^2 +16 = 0
$$

Comment: Do you mean $8r^2$ here? In which case it is a quadrating in $q=r^2$

Comment: @MarkBennet: That would also explain OP's comment “An answer is given as 2i and -2i” below.

Comment: If it's an exercise from your text, then it's likely the middle term is supposed to be a square.

Comment: $2i$ and $-2i$ are the roots of $r^4+8r^2+16=0$.  They are NOT roots of $r^4 + 8r +16 = 0$.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that guys. The middle term is squared.

Comment: Also: I don't see what this has to do with Ordinary Differential Equations? I don't see any differentials ...

Comment: It is a characteristic equation of the homogeneous Differential equation Y'''' + 8y'' + 16 = 0. After finding the roots they plug into the formula for complex conjugates and we have a solution for y sub h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take $X := r^2$, your equation becomes $X^2 +8X + 16=0$. You get a double root : $-4$, whence r^2=-4 and the result.

Now, what to if you get $r^2 = z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$?

The trick is to write $z$ in polar form : say $z=a + i b, \, a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Compute the module $\rho$ and the argument $\theta$ of z, so $z= \rho e^{i\theta}$. You'll get :

$$r^2 = z \Longleftrightarrow r = \sqrt{\rho} e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}} \textrm{ or } \sqrt{\rho} e^{i(\frac{\theta}{2} + \pi)}$$

Comment: That sure simplified things. Thank you!

Comment: @stoneJax If you liked it, don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer ;)